# Removing part of strings within a column

Tags: r

I have a column within a data frame with a series of identifiers in, a letter and 8 numbers, i.e. B15006788.

Is there a way to remove all instances of B15....  to make them empty cells (there’s thousands of variations of numbers within each category) but keep B16.... etc?

I know if there was just one thing I wanted to remove, like the B15, I could do;

> sub(“B15”, ””, df$col)

But I’m not sure on the how to remove a set number of characters/numbers (or even all subsequent characters after B15).

Thanks in advance :)

Comment: Try `df$col[grepl("^B15", df$col)] <- ""`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Welcome to SO! This is a case of regex. You can use base R as I show here or look into the stringR package for handy tools that are easier to understand. You can also look for regex rules to help define what you want to look for. For what you ask you can use the following code example to help:

```
testStrings <- c("KEEPB15", "KEEPB15A", "KEEPB15ABCDE")

gsub("B15.{2}", "", testStrings)
```

gsub is the base R function to replace a pattern with something else in one or a series of inputs. To test our regex I created the testStrings vector for different examples.

Breaking down the regex code, "B15" is the pattern you're specifically looking for. The "." means any character and the "{2}" is saying what range of any character we want to grab after "B15". You can change it as you need. If you want to remove everything after "B15". replace the pattern with "B15.*". the "*" means everything till the end.

edit: If you want to specify that "B15" must be at the start of the string, you can add "^" to the start of the pattern as so: "^B15.{2}"

https://www.rstudio.com/wp-content/uploads/2016/09/RegExCheatsheet.pdf has a info on different regex's you can make to be more particular.

Comment: The OP says "But I’m not sure on the how to remove a set number of characters/numbers (or even all subsequent characters after B15" which means they want to know how to remove an amount after "B15" as well.

Comment: I read that as "I know how to delete "B15" using `sub`, but I don't know how to remove the remaining text".  Because `sub("B15", "", "B15006788")` returns `006788`, and OP's desired result is to replace anything starting `^B15` with `""`

Comment: However, I'll take away my down vote recognizing that the second part of the question makes the desired solution a bit ambiguous.

Comment: I didn't see anything that says that "B15" would be at the start of the string, But I will add that to the answer just in case. Thank you!

Comment: Thanks for the input, it is if B15 is at the start of the case - sorry for any confusion. That makes sense. Thanks also for the welcome :)